# jquery mouseout issue

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have the following code which is working ok except that the mouseout does not trigger so the icon is left at the mouseover stage.

I have cobbled this code together from other sources so I'm sure it could be simplified.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
jQuery(function(jQuery){
    jQuery('a.fav_me').live('click', function(){
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {
            theID: self.id.substring(3)
        }, function(data){
            jQuery(self).html('<img src="/images/icons/liked-icon.png" alt="you already like this member" title="you already like this member"/>').toggleClass('fav_me fav_delete');
        });
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('a.fav_delete').live('mouseover', function(){
        var entryID = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        jQuery(this).html('<img src="/images/icons/unlike-lrg.png" alt="remove your like" title="remove your like"/>').attr('href', 'includes/favourite-add/' + entryID + '/delete/');
    }).live('mouseout', function(){ 
        jQuery(this).html('<img src="/images/icons/liked-icon.png" alt="you already like this member" title="you already like this member"/>');
    }).live('click', function(){
        var entryID = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {
            theID: self.id.substring(3)
        }, function(data){
            jQuery(self).html('<img src="/images/icons/hug-icon-lrg.png" alt="add to likes" title="like this member"/>').toggleClass('fav_delete fav_me').attr('href', 'includes/favourite-add/' + entryID);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try 'mouseleave' instead of 'mouseout'